# Excel Table Header Value Repeated

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table in Excel, and the value in one of the header cells repeats within that cell. As you see in the accompanying image, the actual value of the cell is "Listing", but it displays as "ListingListingListingListing". If I hit F2 to edit the cell, it reverts to a single "Listing", but as soon as I hit enter it's back displaying the repeated value.

I have not altered the cell formatting, and if I delete the cell value, it displays "Column1Column1Column1".

Table header cell and formula bar

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That particular cell probably had the format changed to fill, change it back to general...

[image]